# xcode 4.1 not updating to 4.2 - how to force update?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I have xcode 4.1 installed. 4.2 has been out and would like to update but need to use the Apple Store but the App Store doesn't think there's an update (perhaps because I had a 4.2 beta installed). Is there any way I can force updated xcode? I run software update

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the "xcode installer" in your applications folder and try again. The app store just donwloads that application installer which you have to run in  order to install the developer tools.. if it does not see that application you should simply be able to download it again ( which is the same as updating anyways ).

Comment: @timpone you are still downloading the whole thing.. we are waiting for apple to fix this, but as an SDK is more than just an application this might never happen..

Comment: would there be any way to keep both versions around? Like have /Developer and /Developer4.2?

Comment: @timpone some command line utilities are updated, but you could always copy the developer folder you currently have and call it Developer4.1 and access the old stuff in there at any given time.. I still have xcode 3.2.1 because its just far superior to xcode 4

Comment: And if one renamed the 4.1 "Install Xcode.app" (to "xcode 4.1 for lion installer") thinking that one could keep it for downgrade/re-install if necessary, one finds that app store updated the installer internally despite its name, making it a 4.2.1 xcode installer that ought to be run rather than ignored during hours of troubleshooting!